# How to do this query in laravel with eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this DB:
[Database model]
[image]

This is the query I want to make in Laravel:

```
SELECT 
  product_translations.name, 
  product_translations.description, 
  products.ean_code
FROM product_translations, products, languages
WHERE product_translations.language_id = languages.id
  AND products.id = product_translations.product_id
  AND languages.language_code = "en";
```

Relationships in Laravel:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function translations ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductTranslation::class, 'product_id');
    }
}

class ProductTranslation extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Language::class, 'language_id');
    }
}

class Language extends Model
{
    public function ProductTranslations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductTranslation::class, 'language_id');
    }

 }
```

is this correct? the raw query works.
thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what have you tried so far to make this query?

Comment: thanks. Tried many different relationships but found the right one now. Need to use belongsToMany on Product and Language classes.

Comment: Can you read for me the return you wish from this query (example of array ,  collections or screenshot from your db after executing sql query )

Comment: I want to be able to always retrieve a product name in a specific language alongside all the product information that is the same, regardless of the translation. I thought this would be easy in laravel, but maybe I'm just not understanding eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

The query syntax you are using is an old style syntax and will produce inner joins for tables. Using laravel you can use builtin methods to query data from your related models.

For your question I believe you need products list but with  specific translation

```
$products = Product::with(['translations' => function($query)
{
    $query->join('product_translations as pt', 'products.id', '=', 'pt.cart_id')
          ->join('languages as l', 'l.id', '=', 'pt.language_id')
          ->where('l.language_code', '=', 'en')
          ->first();

}])->get();
```

Or if you want to go with query builder you can write as

```
$products = DB::table('products AS p')
    ->select([
    'p.id',
    'p.is_organic',
    'pt.name',
    'pt.description',
    'pt.ean_code'
    ])
    ->join('product_translations AS pt', 'pt.product_id', '=', 'p.id' )
    ->join('languages AS l', 'pt.language_id', '=', 'l.id')
    ->where('l.language_code','en')
    ->get();
```

In SQL

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.is_organic,
  pt.name, 
  pt.description, 
  pt.ean_code
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_translations as pt ON pt.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN languages l ON pt.language_id = l.id
  WHERE l.language_code = "en";
```

Comment: How do you mean "old syntax"? When I did some research on how to design a db for localization I found this solution. One of the benefits with this approach as I understood it was that there's no need to join the tables to get translated text.

Comment: @GustafLindholm you are right using this syntax we don't explicitly define joins but in background it is interpreted as a join query